# New problem to restore with aptoncd on ubuntu 13.04 64bit except hal!

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, restore, hal, aptoncd

I installed Hal `sudo apt-get install hal` but I have new problem!

First I open "APTonCD" in terminal and clicked on "Restore".. now I clicked on "Load" but I get [this](http://oi42.tinypic.com/2zhl6s9.jpg)

```
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ aptoncd

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APTonCD/restore/restoreWindow.py",
line 205, in on_btnLoadFrom
    bus = dbus_helper.DeviceList()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APTonCD core/dbus_helper.py", line
26, in __init__
    self.hal_object = self.bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.Hal', '/org/freedesktop/Hal/Manager')   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in
get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in
__init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in
activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in
start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in
call_blocking
    message, timeout)
**dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited
with unknown return code 1**
```

anybody help? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a compatibility issue with new hal, downgrade hal to version used in 12.x. for it to work. Need be downloaded and installed manually from Quantal files -it is hal-info, libhal, libhal-storage and hal itself